# pandas: compare string columns from two different dataframes of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, compare

I have two dataframes of different sizes, and each has a column of sentences, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'text':  ['the old man is here','the young girl is there', 'the old woman is here','the young boy is there','the young girl is here','the old girl is here']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['text'])
```

and the second dataframe:

```
data2 = {'text':  ['the old man is here','the old girl is there', 'the young woman is here','the young boy is there']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['text'])
```

so as you can see there are some similar sentences in both dataframes. what I would like as an output is a column in the df1 that would indicate true if the two strings are similar and false otherwise:

```
desired output:
text                        result
'the old man is here'       True
'the young girl is there'   False
'the old woman is here'     False
'the young boy is there'    True
'the young girl is here'    False
'the old girl is here'      False
```

I have tried:

```
df1['result'] = np.where(df1['text'].str == df2['text'].str, 'True', 'False')
```

but when i check, it only returns false and no 'true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) if need boolean `True/False`:

```
df1['result'] = df1['text'].isin(df2['text'])
print (df1)
                      text  result
0      the old man is here    True
1  the young girl is there   False
2    the old woman is here   False
3   the young boy is there    True
4   the young girl is here   False
5     the old girl is here   False
```

working like:

```
#removed '' from 'True', 'False' for boolean
df1['result'] = np.where(df1['text'].isin(df2['text']), True, False)
```

Your solution create strings, so if need use for filtering it fail:

```
df1['result'] = np.where(df1['text'].isin(df2['text']), 'True', 'False')
```